# Putting "Bhikkhu" before or after name, is there a difference?

Tags: pali-language, pali, dharma-name

For example there's Bhikkhu Bodhi and Thanissaro Bhikkhu. What's the distinction?

Answer (score 2):

Below you can see some titles and names.

The title is (Sammasam)Buddha and the name is Kassapa, the title is bhikkhu and the name is Sahaka, the title is Mara and the name is Dusi, the title is disciple (*savaka*) and the name is Vidhura, the title is brahmin and the name is Kakusandha.

In all the cases, the title precedes the name in the English translation, just like how we say Doctor Fauci or President Obama in English.

But in all the cases, the title comes after the name in Pali.

So both are the same. One in English and one in Pali.

From [SN 48.57](https://suttacentral.net/sn48.57/en/sujato):

> Once upon a time, sir, I lived the spiritual life under the fully
> awakened Buddha Kassapa.
> *Bhūtapubbāhaṃ, bhante, kassape sammāsambuddhe brahmacariyaṃ acariṃ.*
>
> There they knew me as
> *Tatrapi maṃ evaṃ jānanti:*
>
> the mendicant Sahaka.
> *‘sahako bhikkhu, sahako bhikkhū’ti.*

From [MN 50](https://suttacentral.net/mn50/en/sujato):

> Then it occurred to Māra Dūsī,
> *Atha kho, pāpima, dūsissa mārassa etadahosi*
>
> ---
>
> after attacking the disciple Vidhura
> *Vidhuraṃ sāvakamāsajja,*
>
> along with the brahmin Kakusandha?
> *kakusandhañca brāhmaṇaṃ.*

Comment: very good answer